# netbeans output lines overlapping

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, netbeans, netbeans-8.1

I'm using neatbeans IDE 8.1 && Java-7-openjdk and jdk-8u66-linux-x64

The problem happen when using linux ubuntu or linux mint
but never happen when using windows OS

The problem is when use Scanner it discard new lines and mess the ouput

Example this is the Code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("A ? : ");
      int a=in.nextInt();
      System.out.print("B ? : ");
      int b=in.nextInt();
      int Z=a+b;
      System.out.println("Sum = "+Z);
}
```

output I got:

```
A ? : 50
B ? : Sum = 110
60
```

output I wish:

```
A ? : 50
B ? : 60
Sum = 110
```

Any help ?

Comment: Are you sure about the output, as i get all the entry in same line `A ? : B ? : Sum = 30`

Comment: How do you execute it? Where does input come from? Keyboard, file? I cannot reproduce your output.

Comment: I get the '`output I wish`' using the Eclipse IDE. The problem however, is that the `50` and `60` aren't output, they are input. Still strange that it displays the inputted 60 after the `Sum = 110` part though.. :S I don't have NetBeans, so I'm unable to reproduce it. Perhaps it would be best to separate the input and output.

Answer (score 0):

For the output you wish:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

      int a=in.nextInt();
      System.out.println("A ? : "+a);

      int b=in.nextInt();
      System.out.println("B ? : "+b);
      int Z=a+b;
      System.out.println("Sum = "+Z);
}
```